# ¿Como instalar el controlador mongodb para PHP (xampp) en Windows?

Tags: php, windows, mongodb, xampp

En la [documentacion oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mongodb.installation.pecl.php) de php indica que ejecute:

```
pecl install mongodb
```

Lo ejecute y me lanzo el siguiente error:

> WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update
>   Could not download from "https://pecl.php.net/get/mongodb-1.6.0.tgz", cannot download "pecl/mongodb" (Connection to `pecl.php.net:443' failed: Unable to find the socket transport "ssl" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP?)
>   Error: cannot download "pecl/mongodb"
>   Download failed
>   install failed

A lo cual ejecute lo que indica ahi:

```
pecl channel-update pecl.php.net
```

lo que me dio:

> Updating channel "pecl.php.net"
>   PEAR_Config::writeConfigFile fopen('C:\Windows\pear.ini','w') failed (fopen(C:\Windows\pear.ini): failed to open stream: Permission denied)

Y cuando volvi a ejecutar :

```
pecl install mongodb
```

Ahora el error es:

> No releases available for package "pecl.php.net/mongodb"
>   install failed

Ayudenme por favor no se como intalar mongoDB en php (xampp) windows.

Answer (score 1):

Para instalar [el controlador de MongoDB para PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mongodb.installation.pecl.php) en `Windows` necesitas:

- Buscar la [`DLL`](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb) para la versión de tu `PHP` y `Apache`

  - **Ejemplo**: la version del controlador [mongodb 1.6.0](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.6.0/windows) y la `DLL` para [`PHP 7.3 Thread Safe (TS) x64`](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/mongodb/1.6.0/php_mongodb-1.6.0-7.3-ts-vc15-x64.zip)
  - **Nota**: Para averiguar la versión de `PHP`, y si `Apache` es `Thread Safety (TS)` y su `Architecture`, puedes usar [`phpinfo()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.phpinfo.php)
- Descargar el `.zip` y extraer de éste, solo el archivo `php_mongodb.dll`
- Copiar el archivo `php_mongodb.dll` dentro del directorio `[RUTA]xampp/php/ext`
- Editar el archivo `php.ini` dentro del directorio `[RUTA]xampp/php` y agregar:

  ```
  extension=php_mongodb.dll
  ```
- Guardar los cambios en `php.ini`
- Reiniciar el `Apache` y listo!

Answer (score 0):

Para instalar mongodb en xampp tienes que seguir una serie de pasos:

- Descarga la versión de mongo adecuada a tu versión de php
- Descomprimir el zip y copiar el archivo .dll en XAMPP, en la carpeta `C:\xampp\php\ext`
- Registra el archivo .dll de MongoDB en php.ini
  Agrega la siguiente línea en el archivo php.ini:

  extension=php_mongodb.dll
- Reinicia XAMPP y comprueba la página phpinfo.php a ver si lo tienes habilitado.
- Instalar MongoDB en Windows
- Instala RoboMongo

Y con esto ya lo tendrías solventado. Si quieres más información sobre esto tienes un tuto buenísimo aquí: [Descargar e instalar MongoDB en XAMPP para Windows](https://todoxampp.com/mongodb-en-windows-y-xampp/)

Espero que te haya servido de ayuda. Saludos!